# Trying to make a wattmeter

Tags: shields

I've been trying to make a wattmeter using arduino but cannot find the shield I need to buy to put onto my arduino to make it. There are no such parts in the Arduino Store and online the best I could find is [this](http://www.robotshop.com/en/energy-monitor-shield-arduino.html?gclid=CJD6jtrgiNMCFQmqaQody_0CPQ). This measures the arduino's energy consumption, however, not other things. I am really new at this and thoroughly lost. I would be really glad if someone could help me with this problem :)

Comment: i've built a ton of "things", but i've never used a shield; don't be limited by less than your imagination. the next-simplest is to look for "modules" aka "bricks". there are plenty of Hall-effect based current sensors on ebay, and voltage just needs a few resistors to measure.

Comment: Where did you get that the linked shield only measures Arduino's energy consumption? It is clearly stated that it connects up to three [AC current sensors](http://www.robotshop.com/en/seeedstudio-non-invasive-ac-current-sensor-30a-max.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need an Ampere meter and a Voltmeter. Watts is `Volt` * `Ampere`.

There are logic level compatible units out there for ampere meters ranging from a few mA to at least dozens of Amperes.

Also for voltmeters there are several logic level compatible units available, to plug in your project.

The rest is math. (Watts = A * V )

Comment: P=VI for DC, or for AC with a purely resistive load. For AC with other kinds of loads you should include the power factor.

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly true. I just assumed, it'll be DC.